# Rails check current params before sending new params via link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two sets of links set up to send data filtering params to a model so that I can spit out only data that's formatted in the way that a user is looking for.

For example, a user could click "Monthly" and "One Year", and the model would spit out the relevant data in the past year, broken up into monthly buckets.

**Question:** 
Currently, the links/params are set up as below:

```
<ul class="list-inline">
 <li><%= link_to "Daily", :grouping => "daily" %></li>
 <li><%= link_to "Weekly", :grouping => "weekly" %></li>
 <li><%= link_to "Monthly", :grouping => "monthly" %></li>
</ul>
<ul class="list-inline">
 <li><%= link_to "Today", :period => "today" %></li>
 <li><%= link_to "7 days", :period => "7 days" %></li>
 <li><%= link_to "30 days", :period => "30 days" %></li>
 <li><%= link_to "60 days", :period => "60 days" %></li>
 <li><%= link_to "180 days", :period => "180 days" %></li>
 <li><%= link_to "One year", :period => "one year" %></li>
</ul>
```

However, the user can only ever select one param at a time.  They can click "Daily" which loads http://url/grouping=daily, but then if they click "7 days" it will simply load http://url/period=7+days.

I'd like the above example to go to http://url/grouping=daily&period=7+days, for instance.

Basically, **if** there is a current `grouping` param defined, then the URL should concatenate `period` on the end of the URL (and vice versa).  If `grouping` is not defined, the URL should just load "/period=X+period" (and vice versa for `grouping`)

Comment: So you want to concatenate a :grouping result and a :period result?

Comment: yes, with each parameter defined by a different group of links on the page

Comment: Ok, how are you going to select multiple links? Let's say, if you click on "Daily" you will be redirected to http://url/grouping=daily, but in that view you are going to show the other list for the user to select the period?